# Coffeescript If works, but Else does not

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

This is the partial that is called by the view:

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= link_to "#{key.name} (#{key.description})", key %> (<%= key.id %>)</span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Created <%= time_ago_in_words(key.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <span class="content">
  <% if key.chords.count > 0 %>
    <%= link_to "show chords", '#', class: "showremovechords" %>
    <span> // </span>
  <% end %>
      <%= link_to "remove", key, method: :delete %>     
  </span>
  <div class="chordsholder">
    <ol class="chords">
    <% if key.chords.count > 0 %>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render key.chords %>
      </ol>
    <% end %>
    </ol>
    </div>
</li>
```

This is the jQuery (using CoffeeScript) that toggles whether or not to display the div class= 'chordsholder' when the "show chords" button is clicked.

```
jQuery ->
  toggleChords = (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    if $(@).text('show chords')
        $(@).text('hide chords')
    else
        $(@).text('show chords')
    $(@).closest('li').find('.chordsholder').slideToggle()

  $('.showremovechords').click toggleChords
```

The div starts hidden, and the link starts with the text 'show chords'

The toggle of the div's visibility works, and the text changes to 'hide chords' when it is first clicked, but the ELSE portion of the statement does not work, so the text does not change back to 'show chords' when the div is hidden. Any ideas why this might be happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
if $(@).text('show chords')
```

sets the value and the return value of the expression is always **truthy**.   So your else never executes. `jqobject.text(something)` is a setter. Instead you may want to compare the value..
So what happens here is, it will set the value to "show cords" due to the setter in your if condition and which inturn returns the jquery object which is *truthy* so it goes to your if block which then sets it to "hide cords".

Try

```
if $(@).text() === 'show chords'
        $(@).text('hide chords')
else
    $(@).text('show chords');
```

You can also do this way using the fn argument syntax of text (Unsure about the coffee syntax though).

```
$(@).text(function(_, curValue){
   return curValue === 'show chords' ? 'hide chords' : 'show chords';
})
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! FYI there are no ternary operators in coffeescript. Thanks again!

Comment: But you can do it in one line as `if curValue is 'show chords' then 'hide chords' else 'show chords'`!